# mysql -V shows a different version than mysqld -V

Tags: centos, mysql, centos7, mysql5.7

I'm running centos 7 with mySQL 5.7.xxx.  `mysql -V` shows `Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.26-29`, but `mysqld -V` shows `Ver 5.7.11-4`.  `systemctl status mysql` and `systemctl status mysqld` both show the same running database.  `SELECT @@version` in the client shows `5.7.11-4-log`.  The database acts like it is running the previous version (some differences in JSON functions, for instance).

Some background: when we started using JSON functions I attempted to update the database to the latest 5.7 version (on my way to updating to 8 preferably), but it didn't seem to work so I tabled it until I had more time.  I'm not really sure what to do next.  I don't know if this is a server problem or a database problem, or how to troubleshoot or proceed.

Sorry I can't provide more information, but I'm not really sure what I'm looking for.  I can backup the database and uninstall mysql completely if there's not a better way to go about it, just not sure what to do, and I also remember reading that you should update your database in place and not skip a major version on the way (ie, 5.5->5.6->5.7->8.0) but I don't know if that's true or not.

Comment: It's server vs client, mysqld is server and mysql is client.

Comment: @asktyagi I asked this on dba.stackexchange also and someone commented the same thing there.  The issue was that the two versions were misaligned.  Not sure how, and I didn't know you could update one without the other.  Just knowing this piece of information was enough to solve the problem.  If you want to write this into an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will mostly see difference between server and client software, in your case it's mysql server vs mysql client, mysqld is server and mysql is client.

Which version you should use listed here based on client features:
https://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-compat-matrix-en.pdf see `Compatibility Between MySQL Servers and MySQL Clients/Tools` section. If you are using bit old version you have search in doc for further details.